# Recursive Program for a Reverse LinkedList

Tags: java

This program is reading through the current linked list and add the data to another linked list. But the data is reversed. My program keeps giving me stackoverflow errors. This program is done recursively.

```
public BasicLinkedList<T> getReverseList() {
    BasicLinkedList<T> list = new BasicLinkedList<T>();
    getReverseListAux(head, list);
    return list;
}

private void getReverseListAux(Node headAux, BasicLinkedList<T> list) {
    Node curr = head;
    if (curr != null) {
        Node newNode = new Node(curr.data);
        if (list.head == null) {
            list.head = newNode;
            list.tail = list.head;
        } else {
            newNode.next = list.head;
            list.head = newNode;
        }
        getReverseListAux(curr.next, list);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, reformat the code and post a sample input and the expected output. How do `Node` and `BasicLinkedList` classes look like? And what sequence of operations throw StackOverflowError?

Comment: First guess: `Node curr = head;` at the beginning is probably responsible for your endless loop and should probably be `Node curr = headAux;`. Your recursive method should get its current Node passed as a parameter. currently you are always starting from your head and never move forward in your recursive calls..